# How can I displaying view with AJAX call from PartialView?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using PartialView and I am displaying 3 news in partial. I am sending news id from partialview to my action result. When user clicked, they can read news which is clicked. My ajax call return all HTML data. I am okey, it is normally but I want to get database data and display my action result.

**NewsPartialView.cshtml**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fright').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Content/NewsDetail/' + id,            


                    success: (function (data) {
                        alert("Okey");
                       console.log(data);

                    }),
                    error:function()
                    {

                        alert("Error");
                    }

                });

        });

    });
</script>

    @model IEnumerable<Models.Managers.News>
    .....
    <div class="news fright" id="@item.ID">Read New >></div>
```

**NewsController**

```
 public ActionResult NewsDetail(int id)
        {

            dbContext = new DbContext();

            var news = dbContext.News.First(x => x.ID == id);
            return View(news);

        }
```

Comment: You need to create another partial view for the news details and pass call the action to get the information from the DB

Comment: @mbadeveloper Thanks for answer. Can I make it with JSON ? For example, I send ajax call to JsonResult. Can I pass JSON data to my NewsDetail ?

Comment: @mbadeveloper I created partialview, I am sending id with ajax to NewsDetailPartial. I can send id correctly but My NewsDetail not displaying, I show again main page.

Comment: NewsDetail is not displaying because in your `success` function you have to actually _do something_ with the content you receive back from the NewsDetail endpoint. So you can either 1) write some JS to insert the HTML into your page somewhere (and also make NewsDetail return a PartialViewResult, for it to work properly), or 2) forget about using ajax, and use make a normal hyperlink which will cause the user to visit that view and move away from the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.location.href. You don't need to AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fright').click(function () {      

      var id = $(this).attr('id');
        window.location.href='/Content/NewsDetail'+id;
        alert("success");
            });        
        });

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fright').click(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
        url: '/Content/NewsDetail',
        data: id,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
        
        }
        error:function(data)
                    {

                        alert("Error");
                    }

    });
    });

    });
```

Comment: what is this supposed to demonstrate, exactly? It does nothing useful as far as I can see. It's also badly formatted and has no explanation at all. I see you are a new user - please heed this advice and improve the quality of your answers.